# SendMessage not Working When Sending Alphanumeric From Another Program

Tags: c#, automation, pinvoke, citrix, user32

I have the following program :

- Open Citrix Connection Center (concentr.exe)
- Bring window to the front
- Send the `R` key (this opens preferences)
- Close both windows (concentr and preferences)

Here is the working code :

```
    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\concentr.exe");
    IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Citrix Connection Center");
    SetForegroundWindow(windowPtr);
    SendKeys.SendWait("{r}");
    IntPtr prefWindowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Citrix Receiver - Preferences");
    SendMessage(prefWindowPtr, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

My only issue with this code as it stands is the use of `SendKeys.SendWait` to send the `R` key, which I would like to replace with a call to `SendMessage`.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to do anything :

```
SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)0x52, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr)0x72, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)0x52, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I got the above lines by running Microsoft Spy++ in Notepad and recording what it does when I press `R`, which gave me the following :

[image]

Does anyone know where I am going wrong / what I should be doing here instead?

Comment: Have you looked at using AutoIt3?  Why are you doing your own automation?

Comment: The way to generate fake input is with `SendInput`. Sending fake input messages with `SendMessage` does not go through the input system.

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm I need to integrate this with an existing C# app - Also the users wont have AutoIt installed on their machines

Comment: @RaymondChen I would love to use `SendInput` but I can't seem to work out how to call it properly ... Do you happen to know of any particularly good reading on this subject?

Comment: [Searching on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+sendinput) reveals [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897759/sendinput-does-not-produce-any-visible-output).

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for the link - I am looking at that answer now, but as per all the other links I've checked it just raises more questions! For example, in the example you posted, the code calls `iKeyDown.type = KEYBD_INPUT_TYPE;` but what is `KEYBD_INPUT_TYPE`??? When I try calling this type my compiler says it doesn't exist, and I can't find any other information on it from google .... I tried replacing this with just `KEYBDINPUT`, but then it complains that it is the wrong type

Comment: You can go back to [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You might consider reading the documentation if you want to know what `KEYBD_INPUT_TYPE` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the correct way of doing this is with `SendInput()`.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482338/simulate-keyboard-input-in-c-sharp/20493025#comment62086585_20493025) and  I was able to get this working. After declaring all the required structs and methods, I was successfully able to send `R` like this :

```
void SendR()
{
    INPUT[] Inputs = new INPUT[1];
    INPUT Input = new INPUT();

    Input.type = 1; // Keyboard Input
    Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.KEY_R;
    Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;   
    Inputs[0] = Input;

    SendInput(1, Inputs, INPUT.Size);
}
```

Other declarations :

```
/// <summary>
/// Declaration of external SendInput method
/// </summary>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern uint SendInput(
    uint nInputs,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
    int cbSize);


// Declare the INPUT struct
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct INPUT
{
    internal uint type;
    internal InputUnion U;
    internal static int Size
    {
        get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)); }
    }
}

// Declare the InputUnion struct
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct InputUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    internal int dx;
    internal int dy;
    internal MouseEventDataXButtons mouseData;
    internal MOUSEEVENTF dwFlags;
    internal uint time;
    internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[Flags]
internal enum MouseEventDataXButtons : uint
{
    Nothing = 0x00000000,
    XBUTTON1 = 0x00000001,
    XBUTTON2 = 0x00000002
}

[Flags]
internal enum MOUSEEVENTF : uint
{
    ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,
    HWHEEL = 0x01000,
    MOVE = 0x0001,
    MOVE_NOCOALESCE = 0x2000,
    LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
    LEFTUP = 0x0004,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
    VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
    WHEEL = 0x0800,
    XDOWN = 0x0080,
    XUP = 0x0100
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    internal VirtualKeyShort wVk;
    internal ScanCodeShort wScan;
    internal KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
    internal int time;
    internal UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[Flags]
internal enum KEYEVENTF : uint
{
    EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
    KEYUP = 0x0002,
    SCANCODE = 0x0008,
    UNICODE = 0x0004
}

internal enum VirtualKeyShort : short
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Left mouse button
    ///</summary>
    LBUTTON = 0x01,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right mouse button
    ///</summary>
    RBUTTON = 0x02,
    ///<summary>
    ///Control-break processing
    ///</summary>
    CANCEL = 0x03,
    ///<summary>
    ///Middle mouse button (three-button mouse)
    ///</summary>
    MBUTTON = 0x04,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: X1 mouse button
    ///</summary>
    XBUTTON1 = 0x05,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: X2 mouse button
    ///</summary>
    XBUTTON2 = 0x06,
    ///<summary>
    ///BACKSPACE key
    ///</summary>
    BACK = 0x08,
    ///<summary>
    ///TAB key
    ///</summary>
    TAB = 0x09,
    ///<summary>
    ///CLEAR key
    ///</summary>
    CLEAR = 0x0C,
    ///<summary>
    ///ENTER key
    ///</summary>
    RETURN = 0x0D,
    ///<summary>
    ///SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    SHIFT = 0x10,
    ///<summary>
    ///CTRL key
    ///</summary>
    CONTROL = 0x11,
    ///<summary>
    ///ALT key
    ///</summary>
    MENU = 0x12,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAUSE key
    ///</summary>
    PAUSE = 0x13,
    ///<summary>
    ///CAPS LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    CAPITAL = 0x14,
    ///<summary>
    ///Input Method Editor (IME) Kana mode
    ///</summary>
    KANA = 0x15,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Hangul mode
    ///</summary>
    HANGUL = 0x15,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Junja mode
    ///</summary>
    JUNJA = 0x17,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME final mode
    ///</summary>
    FINAL = 0x18,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Hanja mode
    ///</summary>
    HANJA = 0x19,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME Kanji mode
    ///</summary>
    KANJI = 0x19,
    ///<summary>
    ///ESC key
    ///</summary>
    ESCAPE = 0x1B,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME convert
    ///</summary>
    CONVERT = 0x1C,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME nonconvert
    ///</summary>
    NONCONVERT = 0x1D,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME accept
    ///</summary>
    ACCEPT = 0x1E,
    ///<summary>
    ///IME mode change request
    ///</summary>
    MODECHANGE = 0x1F,
    ///<summary>
    ///SPACEBAR
    ///</summary>
    SPACE = 0x20,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAGE UP key
    ///</summary>
    PRIOR = 0x21,
    ///<summary>
    ///PAGE DOWN key
    ///</summary>
    NEXT = 0x22,
    ///<summary>
    ///END key
    ///</summary>
    END = 0x23,
    ///<summary>
    ///HOME key
    ///</summary>
    HOME = 0x24,
    ///<summary>
    ///LEFT ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    LEFT = 0x25,
    ///<summary>
    ///UP ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    UP = 0x26,
    ///<summary>
    ///RIGHT ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    RIGHT = 0x27,
    ///<summary>
    ///DOWN ARROW key
    ///</summary>
    DOWN = 0x28,
    ///<summary>
    ///SELECT key
    ///</summary>
    SELECT = 0x29,
    ///<summary>
    ///PRINT key
    ///</summary>
    PRINT = 0x2A,
    ///<summary>
    ///EXECUTE key
    ///</summary>
    EXECUTE = 0x2B,
    ///<summary>
    ///PRINT SCREEN key
    ///</summary>
    SNAPSHOT = 0x2C,
    ///<summary>
    ///INS key
    ///</summary>
    INSERT = 0x2D,
    ///<summary>
    ///DEL key
    ///</summary>
    DELETE = 0x2E,
    ///<summary>
    ///HELP key
    ///</summary>
    HELP = 0x2F,
    ///<summary>
    ///0 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_0 = 0x30,
    ///<summary>
    ///1 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_1 = 0x31,
    ///<summary>
    ///2 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_2 = 0x32,
    ///<summary>
    ///3 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_3 = 0x33,
    ///<summary>
    ///4 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_4 = 0x34,
    ///<summary>
    ///5 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_5 = 0x35,
    ///<summary>
    ///6 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_6 = 0x36,
    ///<summary>
    ///7 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_7 = 0x37,
    ///<summary>
    ///8 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_8 = 0x38,
    ///<summary>
    ///9 key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_9 = 0x39,
    ///<summary>
    ///A key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_A = 0x41,
    ///<summary>
    ///B key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_B = 0x42,
    ///<summary>
    ///C key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_C = 0x43,
    ///<summary>
    ///D key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_D = 0x44,
    ///<summary>
    ///E key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_E = 0x45,
    ///<summary>
    ///F key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_F = 0x46,
    ///<summary>
    ///G key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_G = 0x47,
    ///<summary>
    ///H key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_H = 0x48,
    ///<summary>
    ///I key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_I = 0x49,
    ///<summary>
    ///J key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_J = 0x4A,
    ///<summary>
    ///K key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_K = 0x4B,
    ///<summary>
    ///L key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_L = 0x4C,
    ///<summary>
    ///M key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_M = 0x4D,
    ///<summary>
    ///N key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_N = 0x4E,
    ///<summary>
    ///O key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_O = 0x4F,
    ///<summary>
    ///P key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_P = 0x50,
    ///<summary>
    ///Q key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Q = 0x51,
    ///<summary>
    ///R key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_R = 0x52,
    ///<summary>
    ///S key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_S = 0x53,
    ///<summary>
    ///T key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_T = 0x54,
    ///<summary>
    ///U key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_U = 0x55,
    ///<summary>
    ///V key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_V = 0x56,
    ///<summary>
    ///W key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_W = 0x57,
    ///<summary>
    ///X key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_X = 0x58,
    ///<summary>
    ///Y key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Y = 0x59,
    ///<summary>
    ///Z key
    ///</summary>
    KEY_Z = 0x5A,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left Windows key (Microsoft Natural keyboard) 
    ///</summary>
    LWIN = 0x5B,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right Windows key (Natural keyboard)
    ///</summary>
    RWIN = 0x5C,
    ///<summary>
    ///Applications key (Natural keyboard)
    ///</summary>
    APPS = 0x5D,
    ///<summary>
    ///Computer Sleep key
    ///</summary>
    SLEEP = 0x5F,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 0 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD0 = 0x60,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 1 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD1 = 0x61,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 2 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD2 = 0x62,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 3 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD3 = 0x63,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 4 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD4 = 0x64,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 5 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD5 = 0x65,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 6 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD6 = 0x66,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 7 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD7 = 0x67,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 8 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD8 = 0x68,
    ///<summary>
    ///Numeric keypad 9 key
    ///</summary>
    NUMPAD9 = 0x69,
    ///<summary>
    ///Multiply key
    ///</summary>
    MULTIPLY = 0x6A,
    ///<summary>
    ///Add key
    ///</summary>
    ADD = 0x6B,
    ///<summary>
    ///Separator key
    ///</summary>
    SEPARATOR = 0x6C,
    ///<summary>
    ///Subtract key
    ///</summary>
    SUBTRACT = 0x6D,
    ///<summary>
    ///Decimal key
    ///</summary>
    DECIMAL = 0x6E,
    ///<summary>
    ///Divide key
    ///</summary>
    DIVIDE = 0x6F,
    ///<summary>
    ///F1 key
    ///</summary>
    F1 = 0x70,
    ///<summary>
    ///F2 key
    ///</summary>
    F2 = 0x71,
    ///<summary>
    ///F3 key
    ///</summary>
    F3 = 0x72,
    ///<summary>
    ///F4 key
    ///</summary>
    F4 = 0x73,
    ///<summary>
    ///F5 key
    ///</summary>
    F5 = 0x74,
    ///<summary>
    ///F6 key
    ///</summary>
    F6 = 0x75,
    ///<summary>
    ///F7 key
    ///</summary>
    F7 = 0x76,
    ///<summary>
    ///F8 key
    ///</summary>
    F8 = 0x77,
    ///<summary>
    ///F9 key
    ///</summary>
    F9 = 0x78,
    ///<summary>
    ///F10 key
    ///</summary>
    F10 = 0x79,
    ///<summary>
    ///F11 key
    ///</summary>
    F11 = 0x7A,
    ///<summary>
    ///F12 key
    ///</summary>
    F12 = 0x7B,
    ///<summary>
    ///F13 key
    ///</summary>
    F13 = 0x7C,
    ///<summary>
    ///F14 key
    ///</summary>
    F14 = 0x7D,
    ///<summary>
    ///F15 key
    ///</summary>
    F15 = 0x7E,
    ///<summary>
    ///F16 key
    ///</summary>
    F16 = 0x7F,
    ///<summary>
    ///F17 key  
    ///</summary>
    F17 = 0x80,
    ///<summary>
    ///F18 key  
    ///</summary>
    F18 = 0x81,
    ///<summary>
    ///F19 key  
    ///</summary>
    F19 = 0x82,
    ///<summary>
    ///F20 key  
    ///</summary>
    F20 = 0x83,
    ///<summary>
    ///F21 key  
    ///</summary>
    F21 = 0x84,
    ///<summary>
    ///F22 key, (PPC only) Key used to lock device.
    ///</summary>
    F22 = 0x85,
    ///<summary>
    ///F23 key  
    ///</summary>
    F23 = 0x86,
    ///<summary>
    ///F24 key  
    ///</summary>
    F24 = 0x87,
    ///<summary>
    ///NUM LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    NUMLOCK = 0x90,
    ///<summary>
    ///SCROLL LOCK key
    ///</summary>
    SCROLL = 0x91,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    LSHIFT = 0xA0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right SHIFT key
    ///</summary>
    RSHIFT = 0xA1,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left CONTROL key
    ///</summary>
    LCONTROL = 0xA2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right CONTROL key
    ///</summary>
    RCONTROL = 0xA3,
    ///<summary>
    ///Left MENU key
    ///</summary>
    LMENU = 0xA4,
    ///<summary>
    ///Right MENU key
    ///</summary>
    RMENU = 0xA5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Back key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_BACK = 0xA6,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Forward key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_FORWARD = 0xA7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Refresh key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_REFRESH = 0xA8,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Stop key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_STOP = 0xA9,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Search key 
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_SEARCH = 0xAA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Favorites key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_FAVORITES = 0xAB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Browser Start and Home key
    ///</summary>
    BROWSER_HOME = 0xAC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Mute key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Down key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Volume Up key
    ///</summary>
    VOLUME_UP = 0xAF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Next Track key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Previous Track key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Stop Media key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_STOP = 0xB2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Play/Pause Media key
    ///</summary>
    MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Mail key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_MAIL = 0xB4,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Select Media key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 0xB5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 1 key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_APP1 = 0xB6,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Start Application 2 key
    ///</summary>
    LAUNCH_APP2 = 0xB7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_1 = 0xBA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '+' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_PLUS = 0xBB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the ',' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_COMMA = 0xBC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '-' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_MINUS = 0xBD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: For any country/region, the '.' key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_2 = 0xBF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
    ///</summary>
    OEM_3 = 0xC0,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
    ///</summary>
    OEM_4 = 0xDB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
    ///</summary>
    OEM_5 = 0xDC,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
    ///</summary>
    OEM_6 = 0xDD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard. 
    ///</summary>
    OEM_7 = 0xDE,
    ///<summary>
    ///Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard.
    ///</summary>
    OEM_8 = 0xDF,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Either the angle bracket key or the backslash key on the RT 102-key keyboard
    ///</summary>
    OEM_102 = 0xE2,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 95/98/Me, Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000/XP: IME PROCESS key
    ///</summary>
    PROCESSKEY = 0xE5,
    ///<summary>
    ///Windows 2000/XP: Used to pass Unicode characters as if they were keystrokes.
    ///The VK_PACKET key is the low word of a 32-bit Virtual Key value used for non-keyboard input methods. For more information,
    ///see Remark in KEYBDINPUT, SendInput, WM_KEYDOWN, and WM_KEYUP
    ///</summary>
    PACKET = 0xE7,
    ///<summary>
    ///Attn key
    ///</summary>
    ATTN = 0xF6,
    ///<summary>
    ///CrSel key
    ///</summary>
    CRSEL = 0xF7,
    ///<summary>
    ///ExSel key
    ///</summary>
    EXSEL = 0xF8,
    ///<summary>
    ///Erase EOF key
    ///</summary>
    EREOF = 0xF9,
    ///<summary>
    ///Play key
    ///</summary>
    PLAY = 0xFA,
    ///<summary>
    ///Zoom key
    ///</summary>
    ZOOM = 0xFB,
    ///<summary>
    ///Reserved 
    ///</summary>
    NONAME = 0xFC,
    ///<summary>
    ///PA1 key
    ///</summary>
    PA1 = 0xFD,
    ///<summary>
    ///Clear key
    ///</summary>
    OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE
}

internal enum ScanCodeShort : short
{
    LBUTTON = 0,
    RBUTTON = 0,
    CANCEL = 70,
    MBUTTON = 0,
    XBUTTON1 = 0,
    XBUTTON2 = 0,
    BACK = 14,
    TAB = 15,
    CLEAR = 76,
    RETURN = 28,
    SHIFT = 42,
    CONTROL = 29,
    MENU = 56,
    PAUSE = 0,
    CAPITAL = 58,
    KANA = 0,
    HANGUL = 0,
    JUNJA = 0,
    FINAL = 0,
    HANJA = 0,
    KANJI = 0,
    ESCAPE = 1,
    CONVERT = 0,
    NONCONVERT = 0,
    ACCEPT = 0,
    MODECHANGE = 0,
    SPACE = 57,
    PRIOR = 73,
    NEXT = 81,
    END = 79,
    HOME = 71,
    LEFT = 75,
    UP = 72,
    RIGHT = 77,
    DOWN = 80,
    SELECT = 0,
    PRINT = 0,
    EXECUTE = 0,
    SNAPSHOT = 84,
    INSERT = 82,
    DELETE = 83,
    HELP = 99,
    KEY_0 = 11,
    KEY_1 = 2,
    KEY_2 = 3,
    KEY_3 = 4,
    KEY_4 = 5,
    KEY_5 = 6,
    KEY_6 = 7,
    KEY_7 = 8,
    KEY_8 = 9,
    KEY_9 = 10,
    KEY_A = 30,
    KEY_B = 48,
    KEY_C = 46,
    KEY_D = 32,
    KEY_E = 18,
    KEY_F = 33,
    KEY_G = 34,
    KEY_H = 35,
    KEY_I = 23,
    KEY_J = 36,
    KEY_K = 37,
    KEY_L = 38,
    KEY_M = 50,
    KEY_N = 49,
    KEY_O = 24,
    KEY_P = 25,
    KEY_Q = 16,
    KEY_R = 19,
    KEY_S = 31,
    KEY_T = 20,
    KEY_U = 22,
    KEY_V = 47,
    KEY_W = 17,
    KEY_X = 45,
    KEY_Y = 21,
    KEY_Z = 44,
    LWIN = 91,
    RWIN = 92,
    APPS = 93,
    SLEEP = 95,
    NUMPAD0 = 82,
    NUMPAD1 = 79,
    NUMPAD2 = 80,
    NUMPAD3 = 81,
    NUMPAD4 = 75,
    NUMPAD5 = 76,
    NUMPAD6 = 77,
    NUMPAD7 = 71,
    NUMPAD8 = 72,
    NUMPAD9 = 73,
    MULTIPLY = 55,
    ADD = 78,
    SEPARATOR = 0,
    SUBTRACT = 74,
    DECIMAL = 83,
    DIVIDE = 53,
    F1 = 59,
    F2 = 60,
    F3 = 61,
    F4 = 62,
    F5 = 63,
    F6 = 64,
    F7 = 65,
    F8 = 66,
    F9 = 67,
    F10 = 68,
    F11 = 87,
    F12 = 88,
    F13 = 100,
    F14 = 101,
    F15 = 102,
    F16 = 103,
    F17 = 104,
    F18 = 105,
    F19 = 106,
    F20 = 107,
    F21 = 108,
    F22 = 109,
    F23 = 110,
    F24 = 118,
    NUMLOCK = 69,
    SCROLL = 70,
    LSHIFT = 42,
    RSHIFT = 54,
    LCONTROL = 29,
    RCONTROL = 29,
    LMENU = 56,
    RMENU = 56,
    BROWSER_BACK = 106,
    BROWSER_FORWARD = 105,
    BROWSER_REFRESH = 103,
    BROWSER_STOP = 104,
    BROWSER_SEARCH = 101,
    BROWSER_FAVORITES = 102,
    BROWSER_HOME = 50,
    VOLUME_MUTE = 32,
    VOLUME_DOWN = 46,
    VOLUME_UP = 48,
    MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 25,
    MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 16,
    MEDIA_STOP = 36,
    MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 34,
    LAUNCH_MAIL = 108,
    LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 109,
    LAUNCH_APP1 = 107,
    LAUNCH_APP2 = 33,
    OEM_1 = 39,
    OEM_PLUS = 13,
    OEM_COMMA = 51,
    OEM_MINUS = 12,
    OEM_PERIOD = 52,
    OEM_2 = 53,
    OEM_3 = 41,
    OEM_4 = 26,
    OEM_5 = 43,
    OEM_6 = 27,
    OEM_7 = 40,
    OEM_8 = 0,
    OEM_102 = 86,
    PROCESSKEY = 0,
    PACKET = 0,
    ATTN = 0,
    CRSEL = 0,
    EXSEL = 0,
    EREOF = 93,
    PLAY = 0,
    ZOOM = 98,
    NONAME = 0,
    PA1 = 0,
    OEM_CLEAR = 0,
}

/// <summary>
/// Define HARDWAREINPUT struct
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct HARDWAREINPUT
{
    internal int uMsg;
    internal short wParamL;
    internal short wParamH;
}
```

I also found the documentation for [INPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SendInput()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) useful.

The new code for automating `Preferences` in Citrix Receiver :

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\concentr.exe");
IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Citrix Connection Center");
SetForegroundWindow(windowPtr);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // The window takes about a second to load up
SendR();
IntPtr prefWindowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Citrix Receiver - Preferences");
SendMessage(prefWindowPtr, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Citrix Connection Center") //For some reason I need to find this handle again or it doesn't close the window
SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```